# Java HTML parsers modify page

Tags: java, android, tags, html-parsing

Is it possible to use some kind of an HTML parser with which I will choose information under which tag I want to display, and just clear all the rest?

I tried using Jsoup. Developing for android. durig selection my application crashes due to 'outofmemmoryerror'

Comment: which parser is able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract portion of tag using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) and can separate it out

For Example :

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link" , and ignore the rest
```

Comment: Isn't select method is very heavy and expensive?